# Using temp table for sorting data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Recently, I came across a pattern (not sure, could be an anti-pattern) of sorting data in a SELECT query. The pattern is more of a verbose and non-declarative way for ordering data. The pattern is to dump relevant data from actual table into temporary table and then apply orderby on a field on the temporary table. I guess, the only reason why someone would do that is to improve the performance (which I doubt) and no other benefit.

For e.g. Let's say, there is a user table. The table might contain rows in millions. We want to retrieve all the users whose first name starts with 'G' and sorted by first name. The natural and more declarative way to implement a SQL query for this scenario is:

**More natural and declarative way**

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE NAME LIKE 'G%'
ORDER BY Name
```

**Verbose way**

```
SELECT * INTO TempTable
FROM Users
WHERE NAME LIKE 'G%'

SELECT * FROM TempTable
ORDER BY Name
```

With that context, I have few questions:

1. Will there be any performance difference between two ways if there is **no index** on the first name field. If yes, which one would be better.
2. Will there be any performance difference between two ways if there is an **index** on the first name field. If yes, which one would be better.
3. Should not the SQL Server optimizer generate same execution plan for both the ways?
4. Is there any benefit in writing a verbose way from any other persective like locking/blocking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only benefit i see in this is if we want to sort on a column that is not indexed in the parent table

Comment: In the context where you saw the pattern did you test both ways?   Is the temp table used in other selects?

Comment: @Blam: I did not got your question. I did not perform any performance comparison. I just saw the above SQL statement (verbose way) and the question came to me. I could not convince my self that it can be of help in performance improvment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reguzlarly: Anti pattern by people without an idea what they do.

SOMETIMES: ok, because SQL Server has a problem that is not resolvable otherwise - not seen that one in yeas, though.

It makes things slower because it forces the tmpddb table to be fully populated FIRST, while otherwise the query could POSSIBLY be resoled more efficiently.

last time I saw that was like 3 years ago. We got it 3 times as fast by not being smart and using a tempdb table ;)

Answers:

1: No, it still needs a table scan, obviously.

2: Possibly - depends on data amount, but an index seek by index would contain the data in order already (as the index is ordered by content).

3: no. Obviously. Query plan optimization is statement by statement. By cutting the execution in 2, the query optimizer CAN NOT merge the join into the first statement.

4: Only if you run into a query optimizer issue or a limitation of how many tables you can join - not in that degenerate case (degenerate in a technical meaning - i.e. very simplistic). BUt if you need to join MANY MANY tables it may be better to go with an interim step.

Comment: +1. In short, using temp table to sort data in such simplistic scenarios (one scenario is mentioned in the example) will not improve any performance but on the contrary it might degrade. Right?

Comment: Noot may, will. it HAS to materialize the data into a temp table, without regards to order, then order - that kills any way for the query optimizer to see that the order is there in the select, and means you can not return data UNTIL the whole table is finished, which may happen otherwise. VERY bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is never any benefit of the second approach that I can think of.

It means if the data is available pre-ordered SQL Server can't take advantage of this and adds an unnecessary blocking operator and additional sort to the plan.

In the case that the data is not available pre-ordered SQL Server will sort it in a work table either in memory or `tempdb` anyway and adding an explicit `#temp` table just adds an unnecessary additional step.

**Edit**

I suppose one case where the second approach could give an apparent benefit might be if the presence of the `ORDER BY` caused SQL Server to choose a different plan that turned out to be sub optimal. In which case I would resolve that in a different way by either improving statistics or by using hints/query rewrite to avoid the undesired plan.

Answer (score 0):

If the field you want to do an order by on is not indexed, you could put everything into a temp table and index it and then do the ordering and it might be faster. You would have to test to make sure.

Comment: Wouldn't the data need to be sorted to create the index? In which case why bother? Just seems to add additional overhead on top of a normal sort.